# Blank parameter with multivalue parameter returns nothing

Tags: reporting-services

I have three parameter (@person_id, @Person_name, @Supervisor_name), all have *Allow Multiple Values* and *Allow blank value* property enabled.

Columns of the report are Person_id, Person_name, Supervisor_name, Claims_done, average_claims_perday created with dataset table with same columns.

The dataset which return the data has filter in query:

```sql
where @person_id in (@person_id) 
or [PersonName] in (@Person_name)
or Supervisor_name in (@supervisor_name)
```

The requirement is out of three parameter, if any of the parameter is blank, then query should gives the result based on the parameters that are selected with multivalued.

For Example: dataset creates the following result.

11, abc, john, 12, 3
22, def, john, 345, 9
33, ghi, bryan, 89, 7
44, jkl, bryan, 45, 6
55, mno, bryan, 60, 7

If I select the parmeter @Person_name = 'mno' and @Supervisor_name = 'John' and kept @person_id blank then it should give the result:

11, abc, john, 12, 3
22, def, john, 345, 9
55, mno, bryan, 60, 7

If I select @person_id = 11, 44 and @Supervisorname  = 'John', and left the @Person_name blank, then it should give the result:

11, abc, john, 12, 3
22, def, john, 345, 9
44, jkl, bryan, 45, 6

When I keep any of the parameter blank, the report doesnt shows anything, If I select at least one value for all parameters, it gives perfect result.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your requirements for handling parameters can be rephrased as: *If a parameter is set, then filter on it; otherwise don't filter on it.*

If that is correct, change the where clause to something like this:

```sql
WHERE (Person_id in (@person_id) OR @person_id = '')
AND (PersonName in (@Person_name) OR @Person_name = '')
AND (Supervisor_name in (@supervisor_name) OR @supervisor_name = '')
```

This means *each* parameter has to be *either* satisfied, *or* has to be blank.